# how to set the thumbnail display onfacebook share link

Tags: facebook

I have a problem about the thumbnail display in Facebook.

I have set the thumbnail image in the link display and the Facebook also can capture the image when someone share the link.

But I hope the image diplay at the more accurate position not like being enlarged and exceeding the bound.

Now my Facebook meta og setting is below:

```
meta(property="og:image", content="example.png")
meta(property="og:image:type", content="image/png")
meta(property="og:image:width", content="200")
meta(property="og:image:height", content="200")
```

Take Yahoo! for instance:

img link: http://imgur.com/IKzHoZT

The logo of Yahoo is a vertical center.
I hope I can have the same display, but I don't know how to make it.

My image size is 500*500.

Does anyone can help me?

Thank you!